# Android Intent issue

Tags: android

I want to show the details of a calculation in another activity when click on a button.
How to achieve this.
my first activity java code is

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
   if(v.getId()==R.id.Button07) 
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(AdvancedCalculator.this,calculatedData.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The calculation i want to do is

```
String a,b;
Integer vis;
a = txtbox3.getText().toString();
b = textview1.getText().toString();
vis = (Integer.parseInt(a)*Integer.parseInt(b))/100;
tv.setText(vis.toString());
```

i want the result 'tv' to be shown in next activity when i press the submit button.
Where I need to include this calculation.and what are the further steps

Any help is greatly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your first activity:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    //Put your calculation code here

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("answer", youranswer);
    //You could also use putInteger, whichever you prefer.

    Intent intent=new Intent(AdvancedCalculator.this,calculatedData.class);     
    intent.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(intent);


}
```

In your second activity, in the onCreate put this:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String answer = b.getString("answer");
```

Answer is your key. it is used to identify what you want to get from the bundle. Using unique keys means you can pass more than one value to the next activity, if you want.

Comment: I have modified my code in the first activity class but the app is crashing everytime i tried running it. My activity class looks like this

Comment: You didn't post any code there. You'll need to mess with it a bit to get it to show.